# Make "Makefile" look nicer

Tags: c++, makefile, bin

My makefile works alright (GNU Make), but I was wondering whether

- There is a way to make a new directory "bin" and put all the .o in there
- If the answer to "1" is "yes", can the instruction "make clean" delete the folder "bin"?
- Avoid having to write all the .cpp and .o filenames?

> ```
> CFLAGS = -Wall -g
> CC = g++
> EXEC = main
> OBJ = listpath.o Parser.o main.o
>
> all: $(EXEC)
>
> listpath.o: src/listpath.cpp
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/listpath.cpp
>
> Parser.o: src/Parser.cpp 
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/Parser.cpp
>
> main.o: src/main.cpp
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c src/main.cpp
>
> $(EXEC): $(OBJ)
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXEC)
>
> .cpp.o:
>   $(CFLAGS) $<
>
> .PHONY: clean
> clean:
>   rm $(OBJ) $(EXEC)
> ```

Comment: What make dialect is it supposed to work with? POSIX make? GNU make? Something else entirely?

Comment: If you use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`, you'll be able to take advantage of a lot of implicit rules.

Comment: GNU make. I've edited my post.

Comment: How about using CMake? Gives you out-of-tree builds for free, and you do not need to list `.o` names (and can, but perhaps shouldn't, use wildcards to collect source files). It also does nearly everything else you'd ever want with less hassle, and gives you great portability from the get-go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the last question, you can define implicit rules to convert .c files to .o files.

```
bin/%.o : src/%.cpp | bin
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This will also out the .o files to the bin/ directory.

Now your result rule will look like:

```
$(EXEC): $(addprefix bin/, $(OBJ))
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

To clean the bin/ directory, simple change your clean rule to:

```
clean:
  rm -rf bin/ $(EXEC)
```

Finally, add a rule to create the bin directory:

```
bin:
  mkdir -p bin
```

Comment: I edited my makefile with your suggestions, but it doesn't work. It says: "Fatal error: can't create bin/listpath.o: No such file or directory". I guess I'm missing the instruction to create the "bin" folder?

Comment: @I19, yes, you need to add a rule to make the `bin` directory.  Something like:  `bin:` with the recipe `mkdir -p bin`.

Comment: @I19, you also need to make your `.o` rules depend on the `bin` directory.

Comment: Added the rules relating to the bin/ directory now.

Comment: Ok I've got this so far:
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

CC = g++

EXEC = tp
OBJ = listpath.o Parser.o main.o

all: $(EXEC)


$(EXEC): $(addprefix bin/, $(OBJ))
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

bin/%.o : src/%.cpp
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.cpp.o:
 $(CFLAGS) $<

bin:
 mkdir bin

.PHONY: clean
clean:
 rm -rf bin/ $(EXEC)

Comment: @I19, this answer seems complete to me with epsalon's changes and a couple of edits I made to clean up some corner case weirdness.

Comment: @CarlNorum: yes, it works now! I wonder what this line means though... "bin/%.o : src/%.cpp | bin"?

Comment: @I19, `bin` in that line is an order-only prerequisite, meaning that the actual output file doesn't depend on anything that happens building that rule, just that that rule has to be run first.  You can check the make manual for more detail, but really the important thing is that having order-only prerequisites defined properly will reuduce spurious and unnecessary rebuilding of unchanged source files.  You can demonstrate it to yourself. Start with a clean build, and then type `make` a few extra times. Then do the same experiment after deleting the `|`.  You'll see what's happening right away.

Comment: Oops- you should `touch` one of the source files before remaking the second time to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to specify things from there sources rather than via some intermediate product such as .o files. Use pattern substitution to generate the names of those intermediate products. If you are using the same pattern to compile every file, you don't need to specify it a bunch of times. Use make's patterns.

```
# The first rule that make sees is the default target.
# I like to put the default target right up front so there is no doubt.
default: all

SRC = src/listpath.cpp src/Parser.cpp src/main.cpp
# Or SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

# Generate list of object files.
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, bin/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))

# Compile rule
$(OBJ): bin/\%.o : src/%.cpp bin
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

bin:
      mkdir bin

```
# Link rule
$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXEC)

all: $(EXEC)

clean:
   rm -rf bin $(EXEC)
```

Comment: +1: This answer uses _Static Pattern Rules_. Close to, but much better than, the _Implicit Rules_ suggested earlier. These are definitely the way to go (see the make manual).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some makefile building tool like cmake or qmake. In my experience, not naming explicitly all source files in makefile is dangerous.

If you are onlinux, try out simply

```
qmake -project && qmake && make
```

in your source directory. 
QMake will do all the magic for you creating makefile. I believe, cmake would do it as well.